# Creating RDS database on instance not available over the network with terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds

I'm managing moderately complex infra using Terraform. Among the resources created are a VPC with an EKS cluster and an RDS postgres instance inside. The RDS instance also needs to have a database created on it, with credentials passed on to the application running on the cluster.

I want to create the RDS instance in the VPC's private subnets, so it isn't accessible over the network. If I do that though, I encounter problems in the `plan` stage because the database doesn't exist yet:

```
│ Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: connection refused
│
│   with module.my_module.postgresql_database.env,
│   on ../my_module/database.tf line 16, in resource "postgresql_database" "my_db":
│   16: resource "postgresql_database" "my_db" {
```

If I use multiple `terraform apply` with targets, I can at least make sure the db instance exists, but it still won't be accessible over the network.

The same problem exists for the EKS cluster as well - if I don't make the cluster endpoint accessible to the internet, how can I install the application (and other dependencies (i.e. helm charts, ...)) on the cluster?

I would prefer not to make modifications to the infrastructure after terraform - I think that would be a lot of management overhead.

How can this be solved? Thanks!

Terraform code:

```
module "rds" {
  source            = "terraform-aws-modules/rds/aws"
  version           = "4.4.0"
  engine            = "postgres"
  engine_version    = "13.6"
  instance_class    = "db.t4g.micro"
  allocated_storage = 20
  storage_encrypted = true
  identifier = "app-db"

  username = "postgres"
  password = random_password.postgres_master_password.result
  port     = "5432"

  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.database_security_group.id]
  maintenance_window = "Sat:00:00-Sat:03:00"
  backup_window      = "03:00-06:00"

  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  family               = "postgres13"
  db_subnet_group_name = aws_db_subnet_group.postgresql_subnet_group.name
}

provider "postgresql" {
  alias           = "instance_admin"
  host            = module.rds.db_instance_address
  port            = module.rds.db_instance_port
  database        = "postgres"
  username        = module.rds.db_instance_username
  password        = module.rds.db_instance_password
  sslmode         = "require"
  connect_timeout = 15
  superuser       = false
}

resource "postgresql_database" "env" {
  name     = "app_database"
}

resource "random_string" "postgres_pass" {
  length  = 16
  special = false
}

resource "postgresql_role" "db_role" {
  name     = "db_role"
  login    = true
  password = random_string.postgres_pass.result
}
```

Comment: Can you connect to this rds in any other way? It other words, is the issue only related to TF not being able to connect to it, or the rds is not accessible at all?

Comment: @Marcin Ideally this instance would be accessible only from the EKS cluster. The reason this is unique to terraform is that otherwise I would create some temporary hack to solve this and clean it up after (i.e. a proxy pod in the cluster), which isn't convenient to do with terraform.

Comment: But the error is showing you are calling another module for the PostgreSQL database? It is not present in the question?

Comment: That's true, but that isn't the primary problem and I didn't want to muddle this with more detail. Even with the database creation in the same module it fails because it can't connect to the postgres instance.

I think I'm looking for the "best practice" for creating infrastructure that isn't meant to be available from the network that creates it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the database in the VPC's public subnets, with two security groups.

- One that allows access from the EKS cluster only
- Another that is empty, which I configure dynamically with the local IP only for the duration of the terraform run.

I don't think this is optimal, but it will do for now.